# How to change the number of columns of a gridview for alternate rows

Tags: android, gridview

I want to change the number of columns in every alternate row of a gridview eg first row will contain 1 column, second will contain 2 columns, again third will contain one column and so on. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

They might be few libraries that can help you achieve this but your best option might be to use RecyclerView with their StaggeredGridLayoutManager.

Disclaimer - I wrote a tutorial on it [here](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/). This example may help you achieve what you need